# How to I restart a canceled check on github?

Tags: github

On github, one of the checks for my PR was canceled:

> This check was cancelled

How do I restart the check?

Comment: What CI do you use? GitHub Actions? Travis? Something else? Just restart the build/check there.

Comment: @dan1st It's the github action "Build Verification",

Comment: Yes, but what CI tool do you use for this? Is it your repository or someone else's?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, you must ask for a pr review again.